# Unable to SSH to raspberry pi from external connection

Tags: ssh

I am currently trying to get a *headless* rPi up configured so I can SSH to it from remote connections on other networks.

So far, I have:

1. enabled local SSH,
2. created static IP address for the Rpi,
3. made an account on weaved, installed on Rpi, configured.

Don't have another network to test on currently, but I downloaded the *juiceSSH* app on my android phone, and am connecting to SSH over that. No matter what I do I can not get a response from my external IP address.

Am I missing something obvious? Let me know any details that would be helpful and will post them. Thanks!

Comment: Accessing external ip from within the Lan usually doesn't work

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it does (if the external port is forwarded correctly). Jonathan, try using the internal IP first and check you can SSH locally. If you can, this is a configuration issue in your router (see derjoachim's answer). If not, it's a problem with the SSH install/configuration.

Comment: @JonStory Yes, can SSH locally with no problem. Would the issue still be with the router if I am not using the port forwarding method but rather the weaved method as described in [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/internetaccess.md)?

Comment: Weaved is not a substitute for port forwarding - the port is still blocked on your router. You can access your Pi via the Weaved website, but not directly via your IP: to do that you'd have to forward the port in your router's firewall.

Comment: Even then you mostly won't be able to access it using the extremal ip from within the Lan. Most domestic routers don't have that functionality

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your local network is behind a decent router, can you make sure that external SSH connections are accepted and being forwarded to your Pi? It would also make sense to connect to your Pi from within the network first to make sure that sshd is correctly configured.

For more troubleshooting hints, please see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52486/why-does-sshd-accept-local-network-inbound-connections-and-refuse-external-inbou) or [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58576).

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok I got it! The confusion was caused by my ignorance of how the Weaved service actually works. I was using my own external IP as the host address rather than the new host/port provided by them. I am now able to SSH to my Rpi over cell network on my android phone!

Thanks for the responses, helped get me in the right direction.